# Support multilingual characters in .ics file

Tags: c#

I am using c# to generate .ics file .
I am able to send calendar invite as attachement through mail.
But the invite does not support multi-lingual characters.

How can I enable support for multi-lingual characters?

```
StringBuilder CalenderInviteString = new StringBuilder();

            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Invite");
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("X-WR-RELCALID:{0}",invite.Id));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("METHOD:{0}",(invite.Method==CalendarMethod.UPDATE)?"REQUEST":invite.Method.ToString()));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", invite.StartDate));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", invite.DateTimeStamp));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", invite.EndDate));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION: {0}", invite.Location));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", invite.Id));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:1");
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("STATUS:{0}", invite.Status.ToString()));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", invite.Description));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", invite.Content));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", invite.Summary));
            CalenderInviteString.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}",invite.Organizer));



        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        CalenderInviteString.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        return CalenderInviteString.ToString();
```

Comment: How do you encode the file?

Comment: I have an API  to send the mail.
`Attachement.Add(new EmailAttachment()
                    {
                        content = GetCalendarContent(userTask, content, from, to, method, subject),
                        type = "text/calendar",
                        name = "invite.ics"
                    });`

Comment: Added an answer, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Content-Type (mime type) with an appropriate charset.

Example:

```
text/calendar; charset=gb18030
```

Comment: What character set are you using?

Comment: Can you save the ICS file on file system and post the content?

Comment: I am adding chinese characters, its displayed as ??